# Is there a reason to play Titanfall's campaign more than twice?

Tags: titanfall

Playing Titanfall's campaign twice is necessary to unlock both Titan chassis (maybe some other stuff? ).

I know you can regenerate to reset all your unlocks and start over at level 1, but barring that is there any reason to play campaign mode again after you've completed it twice?

(I ask because it is frequently hard to continue a  campaign partially completed. I keep having to start over!)

Comment: Worth mentioning that it's no longer necessary to complete the campaign to unlock the titans - the Stryder unlocks at level 15 and the Ogre unlocks at level 30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a set of achievements for winning every match on either side which is probably the main reason to continue doing campaign (even though there is no current way to tell which ones you've won).

Another reason is to farm certain things for challenges, like spectre killing. As a few campaign missions contain nothing but spectres, making the grind much easier.

Comment: re: challenges, some missions in particular are good for farming certain Generation challenges! Specifically, ones with NPC controlled titans.